# Compare two arrays and return a new array by removing the child array elements from parent array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const words1 = ['limit', 'exuberant'];
const result = words.filter(word => !words1.includes(word));

console.log(result);
// Output I need(and get): > Array ["spray", "elite", "destruction", "present"]
```

I am comparing **words and words1** arrays and removing the elements of **words1** from **words** and expecting the array result as shown above.

Although the solution,

```
 const result = words.filter(word => !words1.includes(word));
```

works! is there any efficient solution for it. Please help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a set from words1, and then the check for whether an element needs to be removed would be constant time.

```
const words1Set = new Set(words1);
const result = words.filter(word => !words1Set.has(word));
```

Comment: To add to it O(MN) is OP's code complexity, this is O(N).

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `banned` words in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and use the `has()` method to check. The performance of this lookup is O(1) as opposed to a worst-case O(n).

```js
const list = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const banned = ['limit', 'exuberant'];
const lookup = new Set(banned);
const result = list.filter(word => !lookup.has(word));

console.log(result); // ["spray", "elite", "destruction", "present"]
```